# Ninja failing at LLVM during Skia Bindings build

Tags: rust, clang, llvm, ninja, skia

I am currently trying to compile some Rust code and am coming across an error in ninja compilation when trying to compile skia-bindings package in Rust.

```
  Checking for "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-cl.exe"
  Checking for "C:\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-cl.exe"
  ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries
```

The error in question can be further seen with context in the full error code:

```
   Compiling skia-bindings v0.53.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `skia-bindings v0.53.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\(my user name)\Documents\Visual Studio Code\(my project)\target\debug\build\skia-bindings-c451d9d6ef96ce63\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SKIA_DEBUG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SKIA_SOURCE_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=FORCE_SKIA_BUILD
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=FORCE_SKIA_BINARIES_DOWNLOAD
  TRYING TO DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL SKIA BINARIES: 0.53.0/ab8bc4dfa8fc85713027-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc-d3d-gl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SKIA_BINARIES_URL
    FROM: https://github.com/rust-skia/skia-binaries/releases/download/0.53.0/skia-binaries-ab8bc4dfa8fc85713027-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc-d3d-gl.tar.gz
  DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL FAILED: https://github.com/rust-skia/skia-binaries/releases/download/0.53.0/skia-binaries-ab8bc4dfa8fc85713027-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc-d3d-gl.tar.gz: status code 404
  STARTING A FULL BUILD
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CLANGCC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CLANGCXX
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  HOST: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPT_LEVEL
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SKIA_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SDKTARGETSYSROOT
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SDKROOT
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=VCINSTALLDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LLVM_HOME
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=USERPROFILE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SKIA_NINJA_COMMAND
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SKIA_GN_COMMAND
  Probing 'python'
  Python 3 found: "python"
  Synchronizing Skia dependencies
  Skipping "bin".
  skia\third_party/externals/wuffs
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/piex
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/brotli
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/d3d12allocator
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/freetype
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/icu
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/harfbuzz
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/libgifcodec
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/zlib
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/expat
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/libjpeg-turbo
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/vulkanmemoryallocator
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/libpng
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/libwebp
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  skia\third_party/externals/spirv-cross
    IS NOT TOP-LEVEL GIT DIRECTORY.
  Skia args: is_official_build=true is_debug=false skia_enable_gpu=true skia_enable_skottie=false skia_use_gl=true skia_use_egl=false skia_use_x11=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_libwebp_encode=false skia_use_libwebp_decode=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_xps=false skia_use_dng_sdk=false cc="clang" cxx="clang++" skia_use_direct3d=true skia_use_icu=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false win_vc="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC" clang_win="C:\LLVM" target_cpu="x86_64" skia_use_expat=true skia_use_system_expat=false extra_cflags=["/MD","--target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"] extra_asmflags=["--target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"]
  Done. Made 86 targets from 33 files in 1600ms
  ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\(my user name)\Documents\Visual Studio Code\(my project)\target\debug\build\skia-bindings-24372a3e41696695\out\skia'
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
  [0/1] Regenerating ninja files

  --- stderr
  Checking for "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-cl.exe"
  Checking for "C:\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-cl.exe"
  ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

  thread 'main' panicked at '`ninja` returned an error, please check the output for details.', C:\Users\(my user name)\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\skia-bindings-0.53.0\build_support\skia\config.rs:485:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

In an attempt to solve this issue, I have tried multiple steps such as:

- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2022 with Build Tools multiple times
- Manually installing LLVM binaries from LLVM github
- Synchronizing system clock

I am not sure what else to try to fix this issue, any suggestions would be welcome. Tyia!

Comment: Can you try the latest skia-bindings 0.55.0?